# Mathematica replace function in interval with third-degree polynomial

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Any ideas, how to replace function in interval with third-degree polynomial?

For example,

`F(x)=a*sin(1*x/b)+b*cos(1*x/c)` needs to be replaced in interval [-10,3] with third-degree polynomial.

Any useful comments or ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a variety of ways of defining piecewise functions in Mathematica, including a function `Piecewise`.  You could start by reading the documentation for that function.

Comment: Look up the Series function in the help system.

Comment: `Series` is a quick and smart way to do that. But look up also the `InterpolatingPolynomial` and `Interpolation` functions. They might be what you are looking for.